# .NET Micro Framework on a ARM Cortex-M3 Core

Tags: arm, cortex-m, .net-micro-framework

I have a [RDK-IDM](http://www.luminarymicro.com/products/rdk-idm.html) from [Luminary Micro](http://www.luminarymicro.com/). This board has a 32-bit ARM® [Cortex™-M3 core](http://www.arm.com/products/CPUs/ARM_Cortex-M3.html). Has anybody tried to run a .NET Micro Framework application on such a device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cortex M3 is a very cut-down core, it lacks an MMU, for example, and is intended to run very simple operating systems.  Specifically, not Symbian/Windows Mobile/Linux/etc.  Rather OSEck, OSEK, iTRON, or similar.  I think this is actually totally infeasible due to that.

Comment: He's asking about .net *micro* framework not .net compact framework

Answer (score 7):

I don't have any hands on experience but based on http://www.microsoft.com/netmf/about/gettingstarted.mspx The smallest footprint supported is 64kb RAM, 256kb Flash and MMU is not required. Therefore your applications needs would be the determining factor.

FYI: the .NET Micro Framework was released as Open Source under the Apache 2.0 License November 16, 2009

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the LM3S6918 (The chip on the RDK-IDM) has only 256KB Flash and 64Kb SRAM but .NET Micro Framework requires 256KB RAM and 512K Flash/ROM!

Read more [here](http://www.luminarymicro.com/component/option,com_joomlaboard/Itemid,92/func,view/id,2781/catid,5/)

Answer (score 3):

We have ported .NET Micro Framework to TI Stellaris MCU, ARM Cortex-M3 core,
currently we have a port for EK-LM3S8962 board, and it is working.

.NET Micro Framework Minimal memory footprint:

- Flash: 155KB
- RAM: 32KB